# Duplicate input type on fly then validate(if exist) upon submission

Tags: validation, yii2, rules

Currently, I am using Yii2 and still learning.

I have a question regarding validation in dynamic html code.

Please see below details:

original code:

```
<?= $form->field($model, "[{$i}]name")->textInput(['class' => 'model form-control'])?>
```

Upon clicking "add new text box (4x)" on fly (dynamically), the codes above will be added, see below:

```html
<input type="text" name="Model[1][name]" class="model form-control">
<input type="text" name="Model[2][name]" class="model form-control">
<input type="text" name="Model[3][name]" class="model form-control">
<input type="text" name="Model[4][name]" class="model form-control">
```

How can I validate all input text if its value is already exists in the database (return message if existing in order, e.g., input text1 value is existing ... so on)?

Would it be possible to validate w/o using JS?

Answer (score 0):

Your model:

```
class MyModel extends Model
{
    /**
     * @var [] name
     */
    public $name = [];

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            // http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-tutorial-core-validators.html#each
            ['name', 'each', /*validation rules*/]
        ];
    }
}
```

Your fields:

```
<?= $form->field($model, "name[{$i}]")->textInput(['class' => 'model form-control'])?>
```